# template function why can't add "cin"?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int x, int y> 
void add()
{
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << x + y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    add<1,2>();

    return 0;
}
```

In Windows10 + visual studio 2017 , it gets an error : Binary > > : the operator of the left operands of the STD: : istream type is not found (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The parameter `x` and `y` is something different from other normal `int` variables?

Comment: If you try this without templates you'll get the same error. Some Google food for you: "operator precedence".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You mean replacing the template parameters with regular function parameters? No, there will be no error in that case (although the parameters would be pointless, since the function would immediately write over them).

Comment: If you get an error, put the error message in your question.

Comment: `x` and `y` are not variables. They are template parameters. What would it mean to read new values into the constants 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, template parameters are different than normal function parameters. Template parameters are compile time constants. Given your definition of the `add` template, when you instantiate it with `add<1,2>`, the compiler essentially creates a function like this:

```
// where 'function_name' is a compiler generated name which is
// unique for the instantiation add<1,2>
void function_name()
{
    cin >> 1 >> 2;
    cout << 1 + 2 << endl;
}
```

Obviously, you can't do this:

```
cin >> 1 >> 2;
```

You need actual modifiable objects to input into, not constants.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void add(T x, T y)
{
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << x + y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    add(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

In your example, `x` and `y` are template parameters, yet you're trying to use them as values in your `cin` and `cout` statements.